# Reactjs typescript i.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

Im trying to display json array with this:

```
<ul className={classes.ul}>
      {logins.map((login) => (
        <li className={classes.item} key={login.id}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={12}>

                <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
                  {login.test}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="caption">
                  {login.test}
                </Typography>

              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Paper>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
```

fetch function:

```
 const [logins, setLoginsList] = useState<Login[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get<Login[]>('https://localhost:8443/api/logins')
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .then((json) => {
      setLoginsList(json)
      localStorage.setItem("logins", JSON.stringify(json))
      console.log(json.map(login => (login.id)))
    })
    .catch(err => {
      let collection = localStorage.getItem("logins");
      setLoginsList(JSON.parse(collection || '{}'));
    })
  }, [])
```

it works on my browser
[image: desktop-version]

but on mobile version i get this error
[image: mobile-version]

i don't understand why this is happening only on mobile version.

Comment: It appears that you are landing in the second block, the catch. Therefore, as the storage is empty, you are setting your login list to an object. Further in the code you are doing a .map on this object in the JSX to render the list. This will fail, as your list of logins is now an object instead of an array.

Comment: looks like the mobile version doesn't have access to the api https://localhost:8443/api/logins (check the errors above), thus, you're not getting any response.

Answer (score 0):

solved by fixing the connection issue